# Check if a string is a date

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, filtering, date-and-time

I have a list of strings,

```
{"BD4675365", "Corp", "Managers", "Syndicate", "2021-03-08", "8434926"}
```

and I need to extract the date. It may be in any position.

Can I match a string to see if it is in "date" format, in this case `****-**-**`, then extract it from the list?

Comment: Have you seen `FromDateString[]`? (And `Check[]`?)

Comment: Does `FromDateString` give a different output if the input is not a date? I suppose this is what `Check` does.

Comment: So `Check[FromDateString["2021-03-08"], 0]`, then remove the zeros.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you want to use it: Do you want to extract the strings that are dates, or do you want a Mathematica date object instead of a string.  You could post-process the extracted strings, but that's an unnecessary step. (You could do what you suggest in your last comment, for instance. There may be better ways, though.)

Comment: Its ok, this worked well, I used `Check[FromDateString[#, {"YearShort", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}], 0]` to only get actual dates, as long numbers are sometimes taken for dates.

Comment: "to only get actual dates as long numbers" -- Right!

Comment: I mean, an integer like 34818332 does not give "not a date" error. It gives a date long in the future!

Comment: Yes, right! I knew what you meant, b/c my first trial was `FromDateString` without any format restrictions, which is probably what you tried, too.  (I was surprised that "BD..." got interpreted as a date!)

Comment: The format `"ISODate"` seems also to work. I'm not sure how flexible/rigid the formatting of the dates in your data is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The pattern "DatePattern[{"Year", "Month", "Day"}]" will match a date. You may use it e.g. inside "Select" like:

```
list = {"BD4675365", "Corp", "Managers", "Syndicate", "2021-03-08", 
   "8434926"};
Select[list, StringMatchQ[#, DatePattern[{"Year", "Month", "Day"}]] &]

{"2021-03-08"}
```

Comment: Holy cow I never even knew `DatePattern` was a thing, and it's been a thing since 2007!

Answer (score 9):

Extract the date strings:

```
dateStringQ[s_String] := 
  Quiet[Check[FromDateString[s, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}]; 
    True, False, FromDateString::str], FromDateString::str];

Cases[{"BD4675365", "Corp", "Managers", "Syndicate", "2021-03-08", 
  "8434926"}, _?dateStringQ]

(*  {"2021-03-08"}  *)
```

Extract the date objects:

```
DeleteCases[
  FromDateString[
   {"BD4675365", "Corp", "Managers", "Syndicate", 
    "2021-03-08", "8434926"},
   {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}],
  _?FailureQ] // Quiet

(*  {DateObject[{2021, 3, 8}, "Day"]}  *)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
(Interpreter["Date"][#] & /@ list ) /. _Failure :> Nothing

Check[SemanticImportString[#, "Date"], Nothing] & /@ list // 
  Map[First] // Normal
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's always an overkill to use regex.

```
{"BD4675365", "Corp", "Managers", "Syndicate", "2021-03-08", "8434926"} //
Select[StringMatchQ[RegularExpression["^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"]]]
```

regex from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22061879/13040423